# How to resolve the shared library of a function in core file, using GDB - when no symbols are loaded?

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-libraries, debug-symbols

I have a core file in which not all shared library symbols are available, the backtrace looks like this:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f63f0cfe700 (LWP 16501)):
#0  0x00007f63f04b19de in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f63f0cf4700 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f63f7a216ea in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f63f512250f in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I want to detect in which shared library the function of frame `#1` (address `0x00007f63f0cf4700`) is located.

`info symbol` does not resolve it, since the symbols aren't available.

I can do it manually - run `info sharedlibrary` and calculate to which shared-library range this function belongs, but this solution is quite cumbersome.

Is there an easier way to achieve that?

Comment: If you have gdb-14 with python enabled, you can try `py print(gdb.current_progspace().objfile_for_address(0x00007f63f0cf4700))`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to detect in which shared library the function of frame #1 (address 0x00007f63f0cf4700) is located.

Besides the solution offered by ssbssa, you could also use `readelf -Wn core` and look for the `NT_FILE` note.

Comment: Does it have more information than `info sharedlibrary`? In older gdb version it seems like writing a script is the best option

Comment: @joepol "Does it have ..." -- just run the command and see for yourself.